# Anonymous interface instance as interface property in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, lambda

I started learning Kotlin recently and I'd like to implement a simple [postfix notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) parser were instances of `MathOperator` interface pick values from the stack and return the result.
The implementation is trivial in plain Java

```java
public interface MathOperator {
  public float evaluate(Deque<Float> stack);

  public MathOperator ADD = stack -> stack.pop() + stack.pop();
  public MathOperator SUB = stack -> -stack.pop() + stack.pop();
  public MathOperator MUL = stack -> stack.pop() * stack.pop();
}
```

However, when I try the same in Kotlin I get "Property getter or setter expected" error.

```
interface KTMathOperator {
  fun evaluate(stack: Deque<Float>): Float

  companion object {
    val ADD: KTMathOperator = (stack) -> stack.pop() + stack.pop()
  }
}
```

How can I implement the same interface and its properties in Kotlin concisely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, in Kotlin SAM conversions are not so handy. You can rewrite your example like:

```
interface KTMathOperator {
    fun evaluate(stack: Deque<Float>): Float

    companion object {
        val ADD: KTMathOperator = object : KTMathOperator {
            override fun evaluate(stack: Deque<Float>): Float = stack.pop() + stack.pop()
        }
    }
}
```

also you can change `evaluate` to `invoke`. Then you can your `ADD` just like `ADD(stack)`

```
interface KTMathOperator {
    operator fun invoke(stack: Deque<Float>): Float

    companion object {
        val ADD: KTMathOperator = object : KTMathOperator {
            override fun invoke(stack: Deque<Float>): Float = stack.pop() + stack.pop()
        }
    }
}

fun main() {
    val list = LinkedList<Float>().apply {
        add(1.0f)
        add(1.0f)
    }
    println(KTMathOperator.ADD(list)) // will print 2.0
}
```

If you're not too worried about maximum performance and a little strange code, you can also write like this :)

```
class KTMathOperator(private val operation: (Deque<Float>) -> Float) : (Deque<Float>) -> Float {
    override fun invoke(stack: Deque<Float>): Float = operation(stack)

    companion object {
        val ADD: KTMathOperator = KTMathOperator { stack -> stack.pop() + stack.pop() }
    }
}
```

Comment: SAM conversion can make your code a little bit easily readable. This whole anonymous concept is not so handy because of it sometimes it clutters the code than improving readability.

Comment: If you try to recreate exactly what Java does, then yes, it can be a bit awkward.  But that's mainly because of Java's awkward way of implementing lambdas (i.e. using a plethora of named interfaces which much be implemented).  'Pure' lambdas have many benefits, as well as brevity; for example, you never have to convert from a Consumer to a Listener because they're different interfaces even though they are both functions that take one parameter and don't return anything.  This case, for example, could be done without any new interfaces, just using the `(Float) -> Float` type.